# Save PHP ForEach Loop value in a Variable as Comma Separated String

Tags: php

I am Trying to Save Foreach Loop value in a Variable as comma separated.For this I have below code so far.It is getting all the values in a list but without Comma. How can I insert Comma after each id

```
$stmt = $con->query($sql);  
$tmp = '';

foreach ($stmt as $row)
{
  $user_id=$row['user_id'];
  $tmp .= $row['user_id']; 
}

echo $tmp;
```

Comment: Well, have you tried actually putting a comma in the string?  You seem to know how to concatenate string, so I'm not really sure what problem you're having.  You haven't made any _attempt_ to add a comma here.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: I tried like this ",".$row['user_id'] but not working

Comment: @AbraCadaver  Would have to be combined with https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

Comment: `$tmp .= $row['user_id'] . ',';` then after the loop `trim($tmp, ',');` to remove the trailing comma

Comment: A better option would be `implode` or possibly even `group_concat` at the DB level.

Comment: tried but giving error

Comment: @roy  Please describe _in what way_ it was not working.  What was the result of that attempt and how did it differ from your desired result?

Comment: @PatrickQ  Or in the loop just `$user_id[]=$row['user_id'];`

Comment: @roy  Also, "giving error" is not descriptive.  Remember, we aren't at your computer.  We have no idea what the background of this situation is.  We only know _exactly_ what you show/tell us, and nothing more.  Please be as detailed as possible.  Help us help you.

Comment: my current code giving me result like 123456 but i need 1,2,3,4,5,6

Comment: @roy  Please update your question to show the exact code that you used in your "I tried like this" attempt, and also tell us what the result was.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Add comma to every item but last one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440537/php-add-comma-to-every-item-but-last-one)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702563/php-for-loop-adding-commas and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701079/build-comma-separated-string-in-php-loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply concatenate a comma onto the id, each time you add to the `$tmp` variable.

```
$stmt = $con->query($sql);  
$tmp = '';

foreach ($stmt as $row){
  $tmp .= $row['user_id'] . ','; 
}
$tmp = trim($tmp, ',');    // remove trailing comma
echo $tmp;
```

In answer to your comment:

```
$v=trim($tmp, ','); 
$insert = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO $dtBe
                        (user_mobile,user_id,posting_date) 
                VALUES ('$umobile',$v,'$posting_date')"); 
$insert->execute();
```

But there is no benefit or security in preparing a query when you have already concatentated values into.

So use a proper prepared and bound approach.

```
$v=trim($tmp, ','); 
$insert = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO $dtBe
                        (user_mobile,user_id,posting_date) 
                VALUES (?,?,?)"); 
$insert->bind_param('sss', $umobile, $v,$posting_date);
$insert->execute();
```

Comment: hi it is outputting the result as comma separated but now I am getting the error while inserting the comma separated value , below is my insert statement which was working earlier without this comma separated value  `$v=trim($tmp, ','); $insert = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO $dtBe(user_mobile,user_id,posting_date) 
    VALUES ('$umobile',$v,'$posting_date')");
    
    $insert2->execute();`  it is giving error `call to a member function on boolean`

Comment: Issue is you need to wrap `$v` in quotes as it is a string now there are commas in it so `'$v'`

Comment: But if you are preparing that query, and you should be, then you should also be binding the values to `?` parameters as well. There is no safety in preparing a query that you have already concatenated dangerous values into

Comment: as i wrap it with commas '$v' it is saving only first value but as i echo it is showing all the values with comma separated

Comment: Are you sure that `user_id` is the correct column? Sounds like that column may be defined as an integer!! If that is the case you cannot use comma delimited list in there! So you would have to amend the data type

Comment: @roy  Are you intending to insert a _list_ of ids into the `user_id` column or a _single_ id? It is not clear.  I think you should really update your question (or delete and post a new one) to better describe what your ultimate goal is here.  Most likely, your approach as a whole is wrong (or at least not optimal) and getting a better picture of what's going on could help us suggest a better way to achieve your goal.

Comment: @PatrickQ I think I fell down a rabbit hole question. Thought I knew better :)

Comment: oh! how can i thank you, i changed the data type , now it is working like a charm

Comment: ___It is almost never a good idea to put comma delimited lists of `id`s into a rows column.___ It makes using that information very difficult later in raw SQL

Comment: @roy  Please know that storing a list (of anything) in a single column is _rarely_ a good idea.

Comment: just want to know inserting like above or a separate row insert for each user_id which one will be faster considering 20 to 30 records per insert as my all the information is same except user_id's

Comment: Not totally sure what you are doing, but it sounds like a link table might be the way to go